# Set Value of PHP Switch case

Tags: javascript

I have an PHP Switch case.  How do I swt the value of "n" using the onclick of a button?

```
    switch (n)
     {
     case 1:
       $result = mysql_query("select * from tblRestaurants order by RestName ASC");
       break;
     case 2:
       $result = mysql_query("select * from tblCuisines order by RestName ASC");
       break;
     case 3:
       $result = mysql_query("select * from tblLocations order by RestName ASC");
       break;
      case 4:
       $result = mysql_query("select * from tblLocations order by RestName ASC");
       break;
     case 5:
       $result = mysql_query("select * from tblLocations order by RestName ASC");
       break;
     } 

onclick = (switch)n=1
```

Just guessing

Comment: onclick is a javascript function try retagging your question

Comment: You don't. PHP is a _preprocessor_ language that generates the HTML and Javascript that is executed by the browser. You're trying to use it wrong.

Comment: It appears you are attempting to call a php function using javascript which can only be done with the proper amount of unicorn tears sprinkled on top.

Comment: Sorry my Unicorn died so I'm on my own!  Seems that I'm up the wrong tree.  I have a series of 5 buttons that populate a list box.  Is there a better way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can set a PHP variable after the page has loaded with a request for a JSON data return... All PHP code is executed before all of the HTML so if you submit a button you can call a java-script function but you can only use java-script functions from that onClick call.
If you insist on not having your page refresh you would have to use a lot of AJAX and get a JSON data return document. But if you are fine with a page redirect you could just have a form submit to the same page and then at the top of the page check if you posted and if so then execute your queries.
Top of Page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['form_submit'])){
//do your queries
}
?>
```

In your form:

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='submit' name='form_submit' value='Go'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AJAX` in javascript. Also, just so you know, the last 3 queries are the same.

Comment: Thank you.  Just dummy code in statement now.  I have a button that runs the query now.  It works fine when I just had one button, but now I need to switch the MySQL statements, so I just need to wet the case.  Any examples that you know of>

Answer (score 0):

onClick of a single buton will return a single value. This means you either need to (1) use some sort of options menu in your form; (2) create some way, if possible to sum the variables to reach one combined result. Based on the PHP it looks like you are trying to allow the user to select one of the 5 avaiable cases and then return results.

To do this I would just use a select box

```
<select name="n">
    <option value = "1"> boom </option>
    <option value = "2"> boom boom </option>
    <option value = "3"> boom boom boom </option>
    <option value = "4"> boom boom boom boom </option>
    <option value = "5"> boom boom boom boom boom </option>
</select>
```

This will allow the user to choose which option they want it set it to the variable n. Then just use

```
switch($n){
 ........
}
```

and it should run whicher case the user selects from the menu above.

Comment: Tried it and am getting an error on this line while ($nt= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $arrData[] = $nt;  Supplied argument is not valid.

Comment: Not sure what else you're doing I was just answering how to set the value for the swich statment. Any other code for this while loop?

Comment: This...while ($nt= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $arrData[] = $nt;

if(isset($_GET["ajax"]))
{
    echo json_encode($arrData);
    die();
}